# Consequences of changing USERPostMessageLimit

Tags: winapi

One of our legacy applications relies heavily on `PostThreadMessage()` for inter-thread communication, so we increased USERPostMessageLimit in the registry (way) beyond the normal 10.000.

However, documentation on MSDN states that "This limit should be sufficiently large. If your application exceeds the limit, it should be redesigned to avoid consuming so many system resources." [[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946(VS.85).aspx)]

Can anyone enlighten me as to how exactly consuming too many system resources manifests itself? What exactly are system resources? Can I somehow monitor an application's usage of system resources? Any information would be very helpful in deciding whether it is worth the time and effort to redesign this application.

Comment: I'm thinking on using the same solution. Did you have any issues?

Answer (score 1):

The resources it is refering to are those used by the threads for receiving/handling the messages.  You can monitor the thread pool size & other resources using the Taskmanager (look at View->Select Columns).  It it may help you identify the specific resource if the consumer is resource locked, look for a resource count that tops out even while your threads are increasing.

However; if you need to increase USERPostMessageLimit then message producer is simply overloading the message consumer; by increasing this limit you are compounding your problem not fixing it.  Reducing USERPostMessageLimit back to the default, and if your message producer cannot post the message try sleeping before retrying, allowing the consuming thread to clear some messages.

Comment: Can you please specify which of the "Process Page Columns" from the Task Manager (Handles, Threads, USER Objects, etc.) we should be monitoring and comparing to this 10,000 limit? I've tested a program that crashes with "Not enough quota was available to process this command" due to this limit but I've not seen one of the columns that grew to 10,000.  Do any of these columns show you exactly how many are in the queue?

Comment: Sorry, this Question was answered a long time ago and my knowledge of this has got very hazy.  The 10k limit is the messages not the resource limit, and each resource type will have different capacities, and it is not a 1:1 ratio.  It is the topping out that your need to look out for.  Ingeneral the solution is to increase your message consumption.  Not increase the capacity to send more.

Comment: In my case it is difficult for me to try and increase message consumption because my program is an add-in to Autodesk Revit.  I can't see inside of the Revit API function that I'm calling so I'm unable to see what's causing the consumption to stop.  I've already reported the issue to Autodesk but I've increased the USERPostMessageLimit in the meantime.